# Bad version of java when running maven exec plugin

Tags: java, maven

My current version of java is 7:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

and I have command `mvn8` where is set `java_home` to 8:

```
mvn8 -version
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
Maven home: /home/.../apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.8.0_66, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/.../jdk1.8.0_66/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-45-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

And now the problem. When I run one of my profile(there is maven exec plugin which generated files) in project:

```
mvn8 exec:exec -P mo2ja -o
```

I got the exception:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
 ERROR:java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be resolved to a type. 
ERROR:java.time.LocalDate cannot be resolved to a type. 
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

So it seems it still takes my system java. Why when mvn version print java8 ? When I change my system java then it work OK. This is some feature of maven or it can be plugin problem which I use ?

**UPDATE:**

when I debug maven exec plugin I see this line:

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: java -classpath ... org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader -control definitions.model -models entity.model,dao.model -source src/main/resources -target src-gen
```

so question is how to use same java version as I am executing mvn

here is my profile:

```
    <profile>
        <id>mo2ja</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.sqlproc.model</groupId>
                <artifactId>sqlmodel</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <classpathScope>runtime</classpathScope>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-classpath</argument>
                            <classpath>
                                <dependency>org.sqlproc.model:sqlmodel</dependency>
                                <dependency>mysql:mysql-connector-java</dependency>
                                <dependency>org.sqlproc:sql-processor</dependency>
                                <dependency>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</dependency>
                            </classpath>
                            <argument>org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader</argument>
                            <argument>-control</argument>
                            <argument>definitions.model</argument>
                            <argument>-models</argument>
                            <argument>entity.model,dao.model</argument>
                            <argument>-source</argument>
                            <argument>src/main/resources</argument>
                            <argument>-target</argument>
                            <argument>src-gen</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: do you set the source and target tag of compiler plugin to be 1.8?

Comment: the message "ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0" shows that java 8 is used.

Comment: no in plugin I have no source and target tag

Comment: see my answer below. i think this is your problem. have faced it before too. please let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: can you paste your pom file or at least the specific plugin configuration snippet?

Comment: ok I posted my profile where is this plugin

Comment: Stop using buggy Maven version 3.0.3 at least 3.0.5...

Comment: well i guess the quick and dirty answer would be to change the executable path to the jdk8 executable or use toolchain as @khmarbaise proposed.

Comment: hm yea that would be nice but is there some way how to get java path of mvn ? I tried ${java.home} but it still takes my system java

Answer (score 0):

Alter your maven compiler plugin to allow level 1.8

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. As you can see in my question I am not using maven compiler plugin but exec:exec which is exec-maven-plugin. And here there is no source and target element

Comment: ok maybe i misunderstood it, because i thought exec plugin was outside the maven scope. even if you use maven with java 8, if you dont specify the compile level, it uses by default 1.5 if i remember correctly. that's why i thought this was the problem. weird. hopefully some other guy can help.

Comment: For such things it is best to use toolchain.